# Why doesn’t netstat display open websites?

Tags: netstat

I’m a beginner in networking and I’m checking the netstat command.

So I opened a couple websites such as en.wikipedia.org

Then I opened an admin CMD and typed netstat
I can’t see this connection showing up in netstat.  I tried adding switches -n (show IP address)  and -f (show fqdn) but I can’t still find this connection.
I tried refreshing the website to no avail.
I tried searching by the CNAME (dyna.wikimedia.org) to no avail

Why aren’t these connections shown?
Any help much appreciated

Windows 10 20H2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, netstat doesn't know the original domain name nor even the cnames – it only knows the IP address, and has to use "reverse DNS" to translate it back to some domain name.

The reverse DNS information of an IP address **may actually be completely different** from the regular "forward" DNS name. This is especially true for shared webhosts or CDNs with hundreds of sites per address, but can also occur even for dedicated hosts.

For example, the Wikipedia webserver's reverse DNS is `text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org` so that's what you should be looking for. Many Google websites use "1e100.net". Any website hosted through CloudFlare will just show up as "cloudflare", and so on.

---

Second, webpages are not video streams – they are documents. This means that by the time a webpage is shown on your screen, most of it has already been downloaded, and within a few seconds **the HTTP connection gets closed** and therefore no longer shown in netstat. Your browser just keeps the page in memory from that point.

The browser will just open a brand new connection whenever you click a link, and once the new page is downloaded and the connection goes idle, it'll soon be closed again. Some connections (especially those used for HTTP/2) may linger for minutes, but rarely forever.

So you should check netstat quickly while the webpage is still loading, or use other tools (such as Process Hacker) which give you an automatically refreshing list.

Though, browsers do *allow* webapps – e.g. chat apps, news sites – to keep a connection open for continuously streaming data (typically using Websockets) if that's needed. And of course, *actual* video streams and similar things will keep the connection open for as long as necessary. But the majority of webpages are ordinary downloaded documents.

Comment: Very well explained.  Super-thanx.